# How to randomly change every character inside the body of a HTML document?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<div id="contents">
    <h1>Article I</h1>
    <section id="sectionOne">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Black world</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">White world</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">666 world</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
<button id="randomText">Random Text</button>

function changeContents() {
    var contents = document.getElementById("contents").innerText;

    var newContents = "";
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var upperAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var number = "0123456789";

    function isLower(character) {
        return character >= "a" && character <= "z";
    }

    function isUpper(character) {
        return character >= "A" && character <= "Z";
    }

    function isDigit(character) {
        return character >= "0" && character <= "9";
    }   

    for (var counter = 0; counter < contents.length; counter++) {
        if (isLower(contents.charAt(counter))) {
            newContents += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
        }
        else if (isUpper(contents.charAt(counter))) {
            newContents += upperAlphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
        }
        else if (isDigit(contents.charAt(counter))) {
            newContents += number[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
        }
        else {
            newContents += contents.charAt(counter);
        }
    }
    for (var counter = 0; counter < contents.length; counter++) {
        contents = contents.replace(contents[counter], newContents[counter]);
    }

    document.getElementById("contents").innerText = contents;
}
```

I want to create a function that will take every character inside the #contents and change it randomly. The changes should not affect the style. The function is applied to #randomText on click event. How can I write it in plain JavaScript only? I write a pretty bad function here and can't get the work done correctly. Please help...

Answer (score -1):

This should work, it's using the [treewalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) api, to quickly find all text nodes:

EDIT: Added reset example.
EDIT: Excluded chars not in alphabets.

```js
function getAllTextNodes(node){
  var currentNode, nodes = [];
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(node, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
    { acceptNode: function(node) {
      if(/\S/.test(node.data)) return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }}, false);
  while(currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode()) nodes.push(currentNode);
  return nodes;
}

function randomIndex(array) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}

function createRandomChar(char) {
  var lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var number = "0123456789";
  if((lower+upper+number).indexOf(char) < 0) return char;
  if(!isNaN(parseInt(char))) return number[randomIndex(number)];
  if(char === char.toLowerCase()) return lower[randomIndex(lower)];
  if(char === char.toUpperCase()) return upper[randomIndex(upper)];
  return char;
}

function randomizeContent(selector) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector);
    var textNodes = getAllTextNodes(element);
    textNodes.forEach(function(node) {   
      node.textContent = node.textContent.split('').map(function(char) {
        return createRandomChar(char);
      }).join('');
    });
}

// example code
function reset(nodes, originalNodes) {
  nodes.forEach(function(node, index) {
    node.textContent = originalNodes[index] && originalNodes[index].textContent
  });
}

var contentSelector = '#contents';
var contentElement = document.querySelector(contentSelector);
var originalNodes = getAllTextNodes(contentElement).map(function(node) {
  return node.cloneNode();
});

document.querySelector('#randomText').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  randomizeContent(contentSelector);
});

document.querySelector('#resetRandomText').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  reset(getAllTextNodes(contentElement), originalNodes);
});
```

```html
<div id="contents">
    <h1>Article I</h1>
    <section id="sectionOne">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Black world</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">White world</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">666 world</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p>
      A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents.
      </p>
    </section>
</div>
<button id="randomText">Random Text</button>
<button id="resetRandomText">reset</button>
```

Comment: didn't poster clearly ask for plain js and not some weird api he will have to learn to understand your solution?
ps - your variables pollute global scope

Comment: Thanks cryix, but I've no idea what is that thing treewalker. I shall take a look later.

Answer (score -1):

```js
(function(){
      var chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      var unfiltered_nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#contents *');
      var nodes = [].filter.call(unfiltered_nodes, function(n){ return !n.children.length; });
      var btn = document.querySelector('#randomText');
      btn.onclick = randomize;
      
      function randomize(){
        for(var i = nodes.length-1; i > -1; i--){
            var word = nodes[i].innerText;
            for(var j = word.length-1; j > -1; j--){
              var random_char = getRandomChar();
              word = word.replace(word[j], random_char);
            }
            nodes[i].innerText = word;
          }    
      }
        
      function getRandomChar(){
          var len = chars.length-1;
          var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (len));
          return chars[index];
      }
    })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body style='padding:5px;'>
  <div id="contents">
    <h1>Article I</h1>
    <section id="sectionOne">
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Black world</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">White world</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">666 world</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
<button id="randomText">Random Text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't respect whitespaces, line breaks and punctation.

Comment: this can be easily added to the chars string if needed. And its not using some crazy api overkill like you do, is short and simple. You want to expand your answer to library may be? lol

Comment: I didn't know the Treewalker API is an overkill. It's a nice way to circle through you DOM.

Comment: dude u need an api to manage dom transition in a 1 page 5 min snippet. wonder why you didnt offer him to package an ExtJs solution

Comment: treewalker is part of the DOM specification, it's a build in feature ;)

Comment: of course. so why not run a web worker that will use a treewalker in an iframe since these are all built in too? did you hear about the K.I.S.S principle in software development or you only read MDN?
ps - it is spelled 'built in'

Comment: no problem :) please 'accept' either of our answers